# `method_missing': undefined method `generators' for #<Rails::Railtie::Configuration:0x000000057583e8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, inherited-resources

I'm getting undefined method error when i try to run rails s command from my linux terminal. i don't have inherited_resources gem in my gemfile.

**I understand that such question has been answered already but this is not so in my case. i don't have inherited resources gem nor it solves the issue for me even when i install required version of gem.**

Complete logs are:

```
/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in 'method_missing': undefined method 'generators' for #<Rails::Railtie::Configuration:0x000000049d2340> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/haml-rails-0.1/lib/haml-rails.rb:4:in '<class:Railtie>'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/haml-rails-0.1/lib/haml-rails.rb:3:in '<module:Rails>'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/haml-rails-0.1/lib/haml-rails.rb:2:in '<module:Haml>'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/haml-rails-0.1/lib/haml-rails.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in 'require'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in 'block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in 'each'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in 'block in require'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in 'each'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in 'require'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in 'require'
    from /home/munib/workspace/mil/config/application.rb:8:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in 'require'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in 'tap'
    from /home/munib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@mil3.2.3/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in '<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in 'require'
    from script/rails:6:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.21

Comment: Check whether the answer in the flagged post works for you or not.

Comment: Update `haml-rails` you are using version `0.1` (literally the first version tagged in github) there is currently a release for `1.0` which does not include the offending line [0.1 error you are receiving](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails/blob/v0.1/lib/haml-rails.rb#L4) **vs.** [1.0 version of the same file](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails/blob/v1.0.0/lib/haml-rails.rb)